# SVN Eclipse ignore folders for all users

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I recently created new project with maven and committed on SVN server from Eclipse. Everytime i build this project SVN wants to commit also .settings, .project and some other files form target folder. I have succeeded to make SVN ignore from eclipse but it will work only for me.

How to make a "global" svn ignore that would work for all svn users? Can it be done only from svn server or it is a possibility that i can do it from my svn client? 
Please suggest any working solutions :).

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the svn:ignore property instead global configuration change. You have to edit/add the svn:ignore property to your trunk folder and should have the following content:

```
  target
  .settings
  .classpath
  .project
```

This can be done using your svn client.

Comment: I already did SVN ignore from eclipse and works. I want when other users will build this project their svn also ignore these files. 
Maybe is a way to create svn-ignore config file and commit it in my project folder or in root folder?

Comment: In Eclipse you have under team -> Add to svn:ignore which is what you need. Furthermore you have to commit your changes to get them visible by others.